# In R, how do you impute left-censored data that is below a limit of detection?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, missing-data

This is probably a simple problem but I just can't work it out. I have a dataframe of biochemistry test results. Some of these tests like `base_crp` are returning values like `<3` because of limits of detection. I need to impute this data before moving forward. I'd like to do this properly, so not just substituting.

I tried multLN from the [zCompositions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zCompositions/versions/1.3.4/topics/multLN) package but it seems to think that all the `<3` values are negative (error says `X contains negative values`). There also doesn't seem to be much documentation out there- is this an obscure package?

I also looked at [LODI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lodi/vignettes/lodi.html) but it wants me to specify covariates for the imputation model- is there a proper way to select these? Anyway, I picked 3 that would theoretically correlate well and used this code:

```
clmi.out <- clmi(formula = log(base_crp) ~ base_wcc + base_neut + base_lymph, df = all, lod = crplim, seed = 12345, n.imps = 5)
```

where base_crp is the variable I'm trying to fix. I replaced all the <3 with `NA` and inserted a new column `all$crplim <- "3"`. However, this is just returning
`Error in sprintf("%s must be numeric.") : too few arguments`.

Even if I can get LODI working, I'm not sure if it's the right tool. I'm only an undergraduate university student with little statistical background so I don't really understand what I'm doing- I just want something that will populate the column with numbers so I can move forward with Pearson correlations and linear regressions, etc. I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a chemist and I want to ask you the important question **Are you sure you want to do this?** Measurement values below the limit of detection tell you something about those samples. The analyte concentration is too low to be measured relative to the signal-to-noise ratio of the technique. This is usually valuable information, not a measurement error. Imputing these values into something else will cause you to lose information about your samples. You should only do regression (eg calibration curve) on measurements above your limit of quantification.

Comment: @BenNorris Thank you very much for your reply- to be honest I'm not sure. I've played around with some analysis only using data above the limit, but surely this isn't valid because there is information in these data points being binned. I know it's not a measurement error but just not sure how to handle it. It's tempting to just replace the <3 with 3 or 1.5, but apparently this is wrong. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a bit of statistical modelling of CRP (C reactive protein) levels before - see [this peer-reviewed paper](https://ard.bmj.com/content/73/8/1495.long) as an example. CRP has an approximately log-normal distribution, and the median value in an unselected population across all testing indications is usually around 3.5 mg/l (most healthy people will be in that "<3mg/l" category). You probably don't want to be using an imputation model, because these are for *missing* data. The low CRP data is *not* missing. You already know it lies within a certain range, so you are losing information if you do the imputation this way.

It is reasonable to want to replace "<3" with a numeric value for regressions etc, as long as you are using this to correlate CRP with clinical findings etc and not (as Ben Norris points out) for CRP machine calibration.

I can tell you from data of over 10,000 samples of high-sensitvity CRP measurements in the study I linked above that the mean CRP in people with CRP < 3 is about 1.3, and it would be reasonable to substitute all of your "CRP < 3" measurements with 1.3 for most real-world clinical observational studies.

If you really need to have plausible numerical values on the missing CRP, you could impute the bottom half of a lognormal distribution. The following function would give you numbers that would likely be indistinguishable from real-life CRP measurements:

```r
impute_crp <- function(n)
{
   x <- exp(rnorm(10 * n, 1.355, 1.45))
   round(x[x < 3][seq(n)], 1)
}
```

So you could do

```
impute_crp(10)
#> [1] 1.5 2.0 1.1 0.4 2.5 0.1 0.7 1.5 1.4 0.4
```

And

```r
base_crp[base_crp == "<3"] <- impute_crp(length(which(base_crp == "<3"))
```

However, you will notice that I didn't use imputation at all in my own CRP models. Replacing the lower value with the threshold of detection was good enough for the purposes of modelling - and I'm fairly sure whether you replace the "< 3" with a lognormal tail, or all 1.3, or all 2, it will make no difference to the conclusions you are trying to draw.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! It's amazing the kind of specific expertise floating around on the internet- can't argue with 10,000 samples...
Just as a follow-up there are a couple of tests with the same problem, not just CRP- in general, how should I approach this? Is substituting with something like LOD/2 typically acceptable for this kind of clinical study? Otherwise all I can think of is fitting a log-normal or normal curve (based on eyeballing the histogram?) to the existing data and using these parameters to impute a tail but this seems hard. Many thanks.

Comment: @houston It depends. I think if you are dealing with something where the lower bound is a tiny fraction of the pathological values (say like troponin), then you really won't see much of a difference whether you replace it with the lower bound, with 0, or with half the lower bound, and I think your conclusions would be justified either way. It would be different if you were looking at, say CRP in the range 0 - 5 and trying to make predictions based on that. I think our lab recently started reporting "D-dimer < 150", which I might impute for some purposes, but usually half the minimum is OK