# In R, how to impute left-censored missing data to be within a desired range (e.g. 0<imputed_value<0.2)

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, imputation

I have some **left-censored data** for CRP (C-reactive protein) and I am wondering how I could impute the values that are below the detection limit in such a way that **the imputed values would be inside a desired range** (here: 0<imputed_value<0.2).

I'm trying to achieve this with the package 'imputeLCMD', but as the installation of 'imputeLCMD' with all its dependencies is slightly complex, I'm willing to hear of other approaches, too.

Please consider the following MWE:

```r
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(imputeLCMD)

# Assign the dputted random data to a data frame
df <- structure(list(participant_id = 1:10, CRP = c("2.9", "<0.2", 
                                                    "<0.2", "8.8", "9.4", "0.5", "5.3", "8.9", "5.5", "<0.2"), LDL_cholesterol = c(195.7, 
                                                                                                                                   145.3, 167.8, 157.3, 110.3, 190, 124.6, 104.2, 132.8, 195.5), 
                     fasting_glucose = c(114.5, 104.6, 102, 119.7, 102.8, 105.4, 
                                         97.2, 99.7, 84.5, 77.4), creatinine = c(1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.3, 
                                                                                 0.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The simulated data frame dputted above and showcased here below is similar to my real data.

```
# View the random data
head(df, n=5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   participant_id CRP   LDL_cholesterol fasting_glucose creatinine
#>            <int> <chr>           <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1              1 2.9              196.            114.        1.5
#> 2              2 <0.2             145.            105.        1.4
#> 3              3 <0.2             168.            102         1.2
#> 4              4 8.8              157.            120.        1.3
#> 5              5 9.4              110.            103.        0.5
```

However, I'm a bit lost on how to continue from here on. In order to impute the missing values for these left-censored data with the package imputeLCMD, I assume that the left-cencored values have to be converted to NAs first:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(CRP = na_if(CRP, "<0.2")) %>%
  mutate(CRP = as.numeric(CRP))

head(df, n=5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   participant_id   CRP LDL_cholesterol fasting_glucose creatinine
#>            <int> <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1              1   2.9            196.            114.        1.5
#> 2              2  NA              145.            105.        1.4
#> 3              3  NA              168.            102         1.2
#> 4              4   8.8            157.            120.        1.3
#> 5              5   9.4            110.            103.        0.5
```

If I now run one the wrappers from the package imputeLCMD, I do get some kind of a result:

```
# Impute the missing data
df_imputed <- impute.wrapper.SVD(df, K = 4) %>% as.data.frame()

# Round the result
df_imputed <- df_imputed %>% mutate_at(vars(CRP), ~round(., digits = 1))

# Place the original CRP next to the imputed one for comparison
df_imputed <- df_imputed %>% mutate(original_CRP = df$CRP)
df_imputed <- df_imputed %>% select(1,2,6,3,4,5)

# Display the result
head(df_imputed, n=5)
#>   participant_id CRP original_CRP LDL_cholesterol fasting_glucose creatinine
#> 1              1 2.9          2.9           195.7           114.5        1.5
#> 2              2 5.8           NA           145.3           104.6        1.4
#> 3              3 5.9           NA           167.8           102.0        1.2
#> 4              4 8.8          8.8           157.3           119.7        1.3
#> 5              5 9.4          9.4           110.3           102.8        0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My issues:

1. I cannot figure how to set an argument for the imputeLCMD package so that the
   imputed values should be: **>0 AND <0.2.**
2. How to make sure that imputeLCMD does not take the participant_id itself as numeric data
   into the impute calculations?

I've seen some [great alternative approaches for left-censored data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63936449/in-r-how-do-you-impute-left-censored-data-that-is-below-a-limit-of-detection) in SO, but it would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong (or right) with 'imputeLCMD'.

Comment: In practice these are often set to 0 or the LLOQ, depending on the situation. In principle, this is a missing not at random (MNAR) problem and would probably be a question for Cross Validated.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila, [I actually did already](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616737/how-should-i-code-a-laboratory-variable-that-may-occasionally-have-under-x-xx?noredirect=1#comment1146315_616737). :) However, at that point, only Tobit model type of an approach was discussed. Unfortunately, tobit() {AER} and {censReg} functions/packages in R do not help if the left-censored variable is a regressor. For that reason, I steered towards imputation of the MNAR LCMD. I am still puzzled why there is so little discussion on this topic and I'm also considering starting a bounty of this question.

Comment: Ha. I still do think this is more of a CV question because this is about imputing values between 0 and LLOQ _in a statistically rigorous manner_ rather than just any values in that range. I've however retracted my close vote, and I have some ideas about how you could possibly use maximum likelihood estimation to generate some reasonable values to impute with.

Comment: I quite agree! Although, in certain scenarios, a question from the OP may find itself in a grey area between SO and CV, leading to mixed reactions from both camps. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use maximum likelihood estimation to estimate the distribution
of your data while using the information that some observations are below
a lower limit of quantification (LLOQ). To get plausible imputed values, you
then sample from the < LLOQ region of the estimated distribution.

Let’s demonstrate with some simulated log-normally distributed data:

```r
set.seed(42)

# Simulate some underlying log-normal CRP values
# Parameters from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63938717/4550695
crp <- rlnorm(10000, 1.355, 1.45)
summary(crp)
#>     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#>    0.011    1.418    3.842   11.158   10.139 2060.559

# Apply a lower limit of quantification to observations
lloq <- 3
crp_obs <- replace(crp, crp < lloq, NA)
summary(crp_obs)
#>     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
#>    3.002    5.019    8.738   18.669   18.107 2060.559     4331
```

For the estimation step, we need to define an objective function; the
log-likelihood of a log-normal distribution with left-censored values:

```r
# Any missing values in x are assumed to be known to be < LLOQ
left_censored_log_normal_log_likelihood <- function(mu, sigma, x, lloq) {
  sum(dlnorm(na.omit(x), mu, sigma, log = TRUE)) +
    sum(is.na(x)) * plnorm(lloq, mu, sigma, log = TRUE)
}
```

Then we maximize the log-likelihood, given the observed data:

```r
mean_sd <- function(x, ...) {
  c(mean(x, ...), sd(x, ...))
}

# Initial values from observed data
theta0 <- mean_sd(log(crp_obs), na.rm = TRUE)
theta0
#> [1] 2.350642 0.924159

fit <- optim(theta0, function(theta) {
  -left_censored_log_normal_log_likelihood(theta[1], theta[2], crp_obs, lloq)
})
```

We can already see we recovered the underlying parameters:

```r
str(fit)
#> List of 5
#>  $ par        : num [1:2] 1.34 1.45
#>  $ value      : num 26786
#>  $ counts     : Named int [1:2] 69 NA
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
#>  $ convergence: int 0
#>  $ message    : NULL
```

Finally, sample from the < LLOQ region of the fitted distribution and
create a completed dataset:

```r
n <- sum(is.na(crp_obs))
p <- runif(n, 0, plnorm(lloq, fit$par[1], fit$par[2]))
y <- qlnorm(p, fit$par[1], fit$par[2])
summary(y)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#> 0.00557 0.62488 1.20758 1.32565 1.97396 2.99494

crp_imp <- replace(crp_obs, which(is.na(crp_obs)), y)
```

We’ve successfully recovered the underlying distribution:

```r
mean_sd(log(crp_imp))
#> [1] 1.337859 1.461132

summary(crp_imp)
#>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#>    0.0056    1.4200    3.8418   11.1576   10.1394 2060.5585
summary(crp)
#>     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#>    0.011    1.418    3.842   11.158   10.139 2060.559
```

---

I’ve now wrapped this up into an experimental [censlm](https://github.com/mikmart/censlm) package:

```r
library(censlm) # remotes::install_github("mikmart/censlm")
#> Loading required package: survival
set.seed(42)

# Simulate left-censored log-normal CRP observations
crp <- rlnorm(10000, 1.355, 1.450)
lloq <- 3
obs <- replace(crp, crp < lloq, lloq)
crpdf <- data.frame(crp, lloq, obs)

# Fit censored linear model and extract (random) imputations
fit <- clm(log(obs) ~ 1, left = log(lloq))
imp <- exp(imputed(fit))

summary(cbind(crpdf, imp))
#>       crp                lloq        obs                imp           
#>  Min.   :   0.011   Min.   :3   Min.   :   3.000   Min.   :   0.0056  
#>  1st Qu.:   1.418   1st Qu.:3   1st Qu.:   3.000   1st Qu.:   1.4200  
#>  Median :   3.842   Median :3   Median :   3.842   Median :   3.8418  
#>  Mean   :  11.158   Mean   :3   Mean   :  11.883   Mean   :  11.1576  
#>  3rd Qu.:  10.139   3rd Qu.:3   3rd Qu.:  10.139   3rd Qu.:  10.1394  
#>  Max.   :2060.559   Max.   :3   Max.   :2060.559   Max.   :2060.5585
```

The MLE model fitting is done with `survival::survreg()`:

```r
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> survreg(formula = Surv(log(obs), log(obs) > log(lloq), type = "left") ~ 
#>     1, dist = "gaussian")
#>              Value Std. Error    z      p
#> (Intercept) 1.3421     0.0168 79.8 <2e-16
#> Log(scale)  0.3749     0.0103 36.3 <2e-16
#> 
#> Scale= 1.45 
#> 
#> Gaussian distribution
#> Loglik(model)= -13460.2   Loglik(intercept only)= -13460.2
#> Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 4 
#> n= 10000
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for, and it's truly fantastic to discover such expertise right here in Finland(!) - although your solution may not be suitable for the most faint-hearted. Having a convenient package with a pre-built wrapper for statistically rigorous imputation for LCMD - the way you did here - would be fantastic. Out of curiosity, would you happen to be interested in taking on the development of such a package? That would be key.

Comment: @jaggedjava I appreciate the kind words. I agree this could be daunting to apply as written here. I had a brief look, and at least the censored MLE fitting is readily available in many packages (survival, censReg, etc.). But there does seem to be a bit of a disconnect in using those censored models for imputation rather than inference. Definitely requires some more background research first, but I could be interested in putting something together.

Comment: @jaggedjava I made a tiny experimental package [censlm](https://github.com/mikmart/censlm) for this, extending the model fitting part to regression models fitted with the survival package. I've updated the answer with example usage.

Comment: I tested {censlm}, it works like a charm and is very easy to use. Indeed, many thanks - I'm sure to use it and I hope that others will too. I have one more question: what if the distribution is normal (e.g. `some_lab <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 140, sd = 3)` and `lloq <- 49`) - how to change your example code in that scenario as far as the lines with `clm()` and `imputed()` are concerned?

Comment: @jaggedjava I'm glad to hear that. For a normal distribution you would just not apply a log transform: `imputed(clm(some_lab ~ 1, left = 49))`.

Comment: Got it. And no need for the   line `imp <- exp(imputed(fit))` in that case at all?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: The code I wrote to my comment above is silly: `lloq <- 49`is below the whole range of `some_lab <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 140, sd = 3)`, so it should have been, e.g. `lloq <-  133`.

Comment: This is an old post, but I added a continuation to my question above, this time concerning ULOQ rather than LLOQ. Eventually, I decided to make a [completely new posting of that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982457/in-r-how-to-impute-right-censored-missing-data-to-follow-the-assumed-distributi). Would an addition to censlm be possible to cover the ULOQ, too?

Comment: @jaggedjava I pushed an update to allow right censored data in censlm with a `right` argument analogous to `left`. I made the changes a while ago but for some reason forgot to commit them.

Comment: Perfect, that makes the censlm package even more useful. I think there is a continuous calling for your package in biostatistics and alike.