# In R, how to impute right-censored missing data to follow the assumed distribution?

Tags: r, distribution, logarithm, imputation

Earlier on, random imputation of left-censored data to follow the assumed distribution has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346589/in-r-how-to-impute-left-censored-missing-data-to-be-within-a-desired-range-e-g/76351041?noredirect=1#comment134713497_76351041) in Stack Overflow. Than can be easily achieved with the [censlm](https://github.com/mikmart/censlm) package.

But what if I wanted to do something similar for right-censored data?

First, imputation of left-censored missing data (image annotation code omitted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

# Simulate log-normally distributed biomarker data
original_data <- rlnorm(10000, 2.3, 0.4)

# Display minimum value
min(original_data)
#> [1] 2.142283

# Set the lower limit of quantification (= LLOQ)
lloq <- 8

# Erase values below lloq for plotting purposes
left_censored_data <- replace(original_data, original_data < lloq, NA) %>% na.omit()

# Display left-censored data (values below LLOQ erased)
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(left_censored_data), binwidth = 0.3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The missing left-censored values can be easily imputed randomly with the [censlm](https://github.com/mikmart/censlm) package, with log-normal distribution here assumed (image annotation code omitted):

```r
library(censlm)

# For imputation, replace values below LLOQ with the LLOQ value
obs <- replace(original_data, original_data < lloq, lloq)

# Compute (random) imputations with {censlm} to fill back the distribution below LLOQ
fit <- clm(log(obs) ~ 1, left = log(lloq))
imputed_data <- exp(imputed(fit))

# Combine the original and imputed data in long format for plotting purposes
overlayed <- data.frame(original_data, imputed_data)
overlayed <- stack(overlayed[, c(1,2)])
names(overlayed) <- c("values", "data_frame")

# Create an overlayed plot 
ggplot(overlayed) +
geom_density(aes(x=values, lty=data_frame, size=data_frame, color=data_frame), alpha=.5, bw = 1.0) +
scale_size_manual("type", values = c(0.5, 3), guide = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But how about right-censored data? How can random values above the upper limit of quantification (= ULOQ) be calculated, if log-normal distribution, again, is assumed?

```r
# Right-censored data

# Set the UPPER limit of quantification (= ULOQ)
uloq <- 15

# Erase values above ULOQ for plotting purposes
right_censored_data <- replace(original_data, original_data > uloq, NA) %>% na.omit()

# Display right-censored data (values above ULOQ erased)
ggplot() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = uloq, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_histogram(aes(original_data), binwidth = 0.3, alpha = 0.0) +
  geom_histogram(aes(right_censored_data), binwidth = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 16, y = 12,
    label = "Values above ULOQ (15.0) right-censored away"),
      hjust = 0, color="blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

One, very painstaking way would be to flip the data horizontally and use [censlm](https://github.com/mikmart/censlm) again, but surely a more elegant way exists?

Comment: I would to get lognormal μ, σ from what you have - from your data estimate mode and FWHM, from those values compute μ, σ using nonlinear solver and use them to verify your data as well as impute right side. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76908488/parameterizing-a-log-normal-distribution-in-sheets/76923979#76923979 as an example

Comment: Thanks for your insight: I ran [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76908488/parameterizing-a-log-normal-distribution-in-sheets/76923979#76923979) in a Python IDE and it works like a charm. However, I have a couple of concerns: 1) Do I start by log-transforming the incomplete data, and then 2) getting the μ, σ from those log-transformed data? Are μ, σ valid for further use, if there is significant right-censoring present in those data (like in my graph above)?

I feel like I can get closer to the solution with your Python code, but I'm still slightly perplexed by what you wrote.

Comment: And looks like there is mode estimator in R, https://r-coder.com/mode-r/

Comment: Yes, I tried a bunch of those functions and compared their results to my own calculations. I found `modeest::mlv()` for mode and `gsignal::fwhm()` for FWHM to hit the sweetspot. `gsignal::fwhm()` requires also `y`, but that can be easily pulled from an ad hoc density `d <-density(your_x, n=10000)` by calling `d$y`.

Comment: Is it working for you? Just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets make a bit more clear what I propose. You need log-normal, therefore you have to get μ, σ from your incomplete data. We need two estimated values.

So, mean won't work because we don't have right tale. Stddev won't won't work because we don't have right tale. But from what you have, there are two values you could estimate: mode of the distribution and Full Width at Half Max (FWHM).
Those two you COULD get from incomplete data

I roughly guessed mode to be 8 and FWHM to be 14-5 (right side minus left side).
Then I took my Python code and just replaced two non-linear equation for mean and q25 with equations for mode and FWHM. And I got some estimate for μ, σ as well as distribution shape and sampling. You just have to find good estimators for mode and FWHM and put them in and it should work

Code, Python 3.10 Windows x64

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LOG_2 = np.log(2.0)

def ff(variables):
    mode= 8. # taken from graph, to be replaced with proper estimator
    fwhm = 14.-5. # taken from graph, to be replaced with proper estimator

    μ, σ = variables

    # taken from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
    mode_eq = np.exp(μ - σ*σ) - mode
    # taked from http://openafox.com/science/peak-function-derivations.html#lognormal
    fwhm_eq = np.exp((μ - σ*σ) + np.sqrt(2.0*σ*σ*LOG_2)) - np.exp((μ - σ*σ) - np.sqrt(2.0*σ*σ*LOG_2)) - fwhm

    return [mode_eq, fwhm_eq]

μ, σ = opt.fsolve(ff, (5,1) )
print(μ, σ)

rng = np.random.default_rng(135797537)
data = rng.lognormal(μ, σ, 200000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=100)

print('mean: ' + str(np.mean(data)))
print('stdev: ' + str(np.std(data)))
```

and code produced output

```
2.286994459923708 0.45557976057161764
mean: 10.930206083816197
stdev: 5.249043744738874
```

and picture

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your input - your answer seems to win. I think that this approach could work in many situations. In the case of my real data (not the above example data), I started getting RuntimeWarnings and it took a while for me to grasp that the values `5,1` in `μ, σ = opt.fsolve(ff, (5,1) )` had be raised to get the script going again. Unfortunately, my real biomarker data is so skewed that I could not get the "whole right tail" imputed. But this approach is a great starting point. Do you have a personal preference to start with `5,1` in `μ, σ = opt.fsolve(ff, (5,1) )` initially?

Comment: @jaggedjava  No, (5,1) it was just a guess. Well, if you're happy with the answer, please accept it and lets move on

Comment: I accept your answer with pleasure. The next task is accomplish with R what `fsolve` did, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maximum likelihood estimation like in [the left censored case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351041/4550695). For convenience, I’ve updated censlm with a `right` argument to do that:

```r
obs <- replace(original_data, original_data > uloq, uloq)
fit <- clm(log(obs) ~ 1, right = log(uloq))
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> survreg(formula = Surv(log(obs), log(obs) < log(uloq), type = "right") ~ 
#>     1, dist = "gaussian")
#>                Value Std. Error    z      p
#> (Intercept)  2.29921    0.00407  565 <2e-16
#> Log(scale)  -0.91770    0.00799 -115 <2e-16
#> 
#> Scale= 0.399 
#> 
#> Gaussian distribution
#> Loglik(model)= -5909.1   Loglik(intercept only)= -5909.1
#> Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
#> n= 10000

imputed_data <- exp(imputed(fit))
plot(density(original_data))
lines(density(imputed_data), col = 2, lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Great - this is a slightly different approach than the one suggested by the previous answerer, as in your approach a log distribution is assumed. Certainly useful in many situations all the same.

Comment: @jaggedjava an important difference is also that with MLE you aren't relying on being able to find summary statistics that can be unbiasedly estimated from the fully observed subset of your sample. You simply use the distribution assumption and the full information you know about each observation.

Comment: I'm sure I'll try this approach next time. LLOQ and ULOQ problems are ubiquitous in biostatistics, and I'm mesmerized that they are not tackled concretely enough in the literature.